# using BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java

How can I use BufferedReader for reading all lines between two concrete line. for example i want to start reading from line1 то line2, can I use this code

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
String line1 = "StartLine";
String line2 = "EndLine";
while (!line1.equals(line2))
{
  // do something
  line1 = reader.readLine();

}
```

I write something like this, but it does not working! Please help me, I am beginner in Java!

Comment: The idea looks right. Use the debugger for your ide or output what line1 is to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Change the loop in following way. You need to read the line in condition and check if it's not nutll i.e. end of file.

```
String line1 = "StartLine";
String line2 = "EndLine";
String line3 = null;

 //Iterate upto line1
while( (line3 = reader.readLine()) != null && ! line3.equals(line1));

//Print the lines till line2
while(line3 != null && ! line3.equals(line2) ) {
     System.out.println(line3);
     line3 = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I try this, but this method prints all lines from file, and ! can't understand why?

Comment: What you want to do.?

Answer (score 0):

First you need another loop to read all lines BEFORE your "StartLine"
and then you will need to be more specific about what is NOT working.
What you expect to happen and what is not happening

Answer (score 0):

You can try using BufferReader's `mark` and `reset` methods:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    String line1 = "StartLine";
    String line2 = "EndLine";
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line1.equals(line)) {
            System.out.println(line);
            reader.mark(100);
        }
    }
    reader.reset();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line2.equals(line)) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println(line); //or whatever you want to do
        }
    }
```

}

You might have to play with the `mark` value, but something like this might work for you.

Hope that helps.