# Understanding how BufferedReader works in Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

Very basic question on how BufferedReader works. Given the string/phrase, I want to find and print it from the file with a lot of text in it.

[using BufferedReader in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307481/using-bufferedreader-in-java) I did some research on this topic and that was the closest result. Not quite addressing my problem though.

So with this information, why does the following code terminate?

```
public class MainApp {

String line = null;
String phrase = "eye";

try {
    File file = new File("text.txt");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals(phrase) {
            System.out.println(line);
           }
        }

    br.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

**My understanding of how this block should work:**

- The while loop goes through each line of text until the condition is no longer true
- Each line is stored in the *BufferedReader*
- Loop is working until the condition of  *if (line.equals(phrase)* is met.
- Prints found phrase.

**Why I think it might** ***not*** **work:**

- readlines are not stored as strings in the *BufferedReader* (therefore they can't be compared)
- faulty logic (most likely the if statement)

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that **"text.txt"** is filled with very long lore ipsum with a single **"eye"** word put somewhere in the middle of it.

Where exactly is the problem? (Don't provide the entire code solution if possible, I'd love to do the coding part myself for the sake of practice).

Comment: What makes you think that read lines aren't `String`s?

Comment: "readlines are not stored as strings in the BufferedReader". What exactly do  you mean by this? Do you mean that the entire line is stored in the String and not the word and that is why you can't compare the line and the phrase?

Comment: Since the "equals()" String method has worked in my conditional statement, i assume that BufferedReader stores the read lines temporarly as something else and then converts it in to strings. My understanding of that was completly off. I also forgot that i store the results in a String variable itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your understanding of how this block should work:**

> - The while loop goes through each line of text until the condition is no longer true

Correct :-) .

> - Each line is stored in the *BufferedReader*

Not correct. The `bufferedReader` does not store any data, it just reads it (Thats why it's called `bufferedReader`). When you call `br.readLine()` it will give you a String with the contents of the line, but it will not store anything itself. In your case, each line is stored in the `line` variable, which is overwritten each time the loop runs.

> - Loop is working until the condition of  *if (line.equals(phrase)* is met.

Not correct. The loop will continue working even if the condition is met. If you want the loop to stop, you need to insert a `break` statement. In your case, when the condition *is* met, it will print the whole line, and the loop will continue. In your case the statement will probably never be met, because the `if (line.equals(phrase)` will probably never be true.

> - Prints found phrase.

Possibly, if the *whole* line equals the phrase. If the phrase is surrounded by other words, the condition `(line.equals(phrase)` will not be true.

**Why you think it might** ***not*** **work:**

> - readlines are not stored as strings in the *BufferedReader* (therefore they can't be compared)

As I said above, nothing is stored inside the `BufferedReader` . You are storing each individual line in the `line` variable. Then you are comparing with the `line` variable.

> - faulty logic (most likely the if statement)

Yes. The condition in the `if` statement is wrong, since it checks if the *whole* line matches the wanted phrase. Also, the loop will continue running, even if the phrase is found.

> For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that **"text.txt"** is filled with very long lore ipsum with a single **"eye"** word put somewhere in the middle of it.

In this case, your code will probably not print anything.

> Where exactly is the problem? (Don't provide the entire code solution if possible, I'd love to do the coding part myself for the sake of practice)

The problem is in the condition for the loop. Hover here to see how it should be:

> `if (line.contains(phrase))`

Also, there is no `break` statement in the loop, so it will print the phrase multiple times, if it exists in the file. (And if the condition for the loop is fixed!)

Comment: **This answer is not correct.** `BufferedReader` is, err, buffered, which means that it maintains an internal buffer, which it attempts to fill every time it has to read from the underlying `Reader.` Otherwise it has no reason to exist. See the Javadoc: and specifically the following statement: 'Reads text from a character-input stream, *buffering characters* [my emphasis] so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.'

Comment: Note that the sudden flood of downvotes is because another user had read this answer and construed it as meaning (literally) that a `BufferedReader` doesn't hold any data from the stream.  I suspect that is not what you *meant* to say.  Nonetheless it is misleading, and answers should not mislead.  Please correct it.

Answer (score 6):

Your code should work. The `BufferedReader Class` just read buffers of data from the stream. It just means it does not read byte by byte from the file (which would take an eternity to execute).

What the `BufferedReader Class` will do is read a buffer of bytes from the file (1024 bytes for instance). It will look for a line separator ("\n") in the buffer. If not found, the bytes will be appended in a `StringBuilder` object and the next buffer will be fetched. This will happen until a line separator is found in the buffer. All bytes in the buffer up until the line separator will be appended to the `StringBuilder` object, and finally the String will be returned to you.

Edit: depending on implementation, the line separator might or might not be included in the String. Other people pointed out `contains()`, however, it would be a lot slower. If you want to find a specific line, do it with `equals()` (Add the line separator in the phrase String). If you want to find a specific phrase within a line, then `contains()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the *line.contains* method, not the *line.equals* which you are currently using

```
if (line.contains(phrase)) {
```

so it is what you're saying *"faulty logic (most likely the if statement)"*

then you can *print the line (or whatever you want to do)*

```
System.out.println(s);
```

if the line is the following :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **eye** consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

it will not match although it contains the *eye* which you want to capture.. so change the if as I mentioned and you are good to go

Answer (score 1):

When you read a line it will also contain all other data on the line

```
some words eye some other words
```

To correctly find if that line contains 'eye' you should call `contains()` instead of `equals()`

```
if (line.contains(phrase))
```

Comment: fundamentally wrong. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) specifically states that the line read will **not** contain the line terminator.